# PySpark: how to add schema to pipe rdd.toDF()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am searching a documentation on how to add a schema in a PySpark pipe when converting a rdd to an Dataframe

I got the following pipe

```
result_columns=[
    "src",
    "dst",
    "other1",
    "other2",
    "other3",
    "other4",
    "other5"
]

result_schema=StructType(
[
    StructField("src",StringType(), False),
    StructField("dst",StringType(), False),
    StructField("other1",StringType(), True),
    StructField("other2",LongType(), False),
    StructField("other3",LongType(),True),
    StructField("other4",DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("other5",TimestampType(), False)
]
)

result_df=step1_df \
  .rdd \
  .somesteps() \
  .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y) \
  .map(lambda x : myfunction(x)) \
  .flatMap(lambda list: [x for x in list] ) \
  .toDF(result_columns) \
  .collect()
```

Now I want to specify the datatypes of each column
What does work but does not recognise the datatypes columns with only NULL values correctly is

```
.toDF(result_columns,sampleRatio=0.2)
```

with a sampleRatio between 0 and 1

what I want is to hand in the schema to the toDF command

I tried the folowing approaches:

```
.toDF(result_columns,result_schema)
```

this fails with error
**TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'StructType' and 'float'**

```
.toDF(result_columns,result_schema)
```

this fails with error
**TypeError: toDF() got multiple values for argument 'schema'**

```
.toDF(result_columns,schema=result_schema, samplingRatio=None, verifySchema=True)
```

this fails with error
**TypeError: toDF() got multiple values for argument 'schema'**

```
.toDF(result_columns,6)
```

or entering any other number works with no error but does not change the final datatypes

What do I do wrong, where is the pipe command for toDF() documented for PySpark?

Comment: Can you not use `list` as a variable? `list` is a reserved keyword

Comment: you mean in .flatMap(lambda list: [x for x in list] ) ? Yes that works in the pyspark pipe. This is not causing the my problem as it works fine if I use sampleRation
and it gives the same error if I name it differently like mylist